# Tor relay using Tomato Shibby Mod?

Tags: tor, tomato

I'm looking to buy a new router (probably ASUS RT-N16), and I'd like one that I can setup as a [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/) relay. I'm not bothered about using Tor myself, so I don't need it to make connections for me via Tor - but I do want to run a relay (not an exit node) for other people that are using Tor.

The Tomato branch, [Shibby Mod](http://tomato.groov.pl/), has Tor support (the only one that does, [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomato_(firmware)#Feature_comparison)). But I can't find much info about it. Will it allow me to run a Tor relay? Or will it only allow me to be a Tor client?

Comment: That is a most noble thing for you to want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked this question on the  tor-assistants mailing list, and revived the answer:

> From looking at it in the recent past, it's a pretty crappy way to run
>   Tor on a router. It is client only, not relay. You're much better off
>   using the actual tor browser on your local machine. The tomato
>   implementation of tor leaks dns and only intercepts port 80 traffic.
>   These are the first two biggest problems with it.

So that's a pretty clear "nope" to me, I won't be able to use Shibby Mod to run a relay, and I also shouldn't bother with using Tomato as a Tor client either.